# Stuck in waiting for review

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I created an app in itunesconnect on May 24th but I did't upload the binary until June 1st.

The status is still "waiting for review" - in the past the status moved to "in review" fairly quickly.

Is it normal to wait several days to move to "in review" - I am worried there was a problem and that I should reject my binary.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I have had both of these happen.  Wait a few more days and it should move to in review.  If not, you can try rejecting the binary as you said and reuploading it.

Comment: Agreed. I had both happen as well. Just wait it out.